# Call multiple button clicks using JQuery, is that even possible?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, callback

This is my first question ever on StackOverFlow...
Hope it's not silly...
Thanks in advance for your help!!

I want to click multiple buttons on the click of one button using JQuery
Example:
Button-1 calls -> Button-2 AND Button-3

The user should click Button-1 and it should click Button-2 and Button-3.
It should also fire its related Server side click events.

Following is what I tried, but it fires only the btnOne Server event click and not the other two.

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"     Inherits="PostBackApp.apppages.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"            integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#btnOne').click(function myfunction() {
                one();
                $('#btnTwo').click();
                $('#btnThree').click();
            });
            $('#btnTwo').click(function myfunction() {
                two();
            });
            $('#btnThree').click(function myfunction() {
                three();
            });
        });
        function one() {
            alert('Client Side One was called');
        }
        function two() {
            alert('Client Side Two was called');
        }
        function three() {
            alert('Client Side Three was called');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnOne" Text="1" runat="server" OnClick="btnOne_Click">        </asp:Button>
        <asp:Button ID="btnTwo" Text="2" runat="server" OnClick="btnTwo_Click"></asp:Button>
            <input type="button" name="btnThree" id="btnThree" value="3" />

            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Web;

using System.Web.UI;

using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PostBackApp.apppages

{
    
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page

    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            bool isPostbck = this.IsPostBack;

        }

        protected void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Key1", "alert('Server Side One was called');", true);
        }

        protected void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Key2", "alert('Server Side Two was called');", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might consider using `$('#btnTwo').trigger("click")` versus just `.click()`. Outside of that, I do not see the need to set `onClick` attribute in your HTML, this is already done by jQuery when you assign the `click` callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this, did not work!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `onClick="yourFunction` to `OnClientClick="yourFunction"` within your `<asp:Button>`'s in order to access your JS functions.

If you keep both OnClick and OnClientClick you can trigger both server side c# functions and client JS/JQuery functions.

This [reference](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/627920/How-to-use-JavaScript-in-ASP-Net) helped me answering this question. I hope this is what you are looking for! :)

Comment: If I click the button individually it works, but only the last click is fired from the series of clicks in the code.